# Suppose $a$ and $b$ are group elements, $a$ and $b$ commute, $|a|$ and $|b|$ are both finite. What are the possibilities for $|ab|$?

Tags: group-theory

This is an exercise in Gallian "Contemporary Abstract Algebra".  Here $|a|$ and $|b|$ means the order of $a$ and the order of $b$.  I know the order of a group element is the smallest positive integer n such that $a^n=e$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group.

I know that since $a$ and $b$ commute then $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$. I sketched a regular hexagon and labeled the vertices $0,1,2,\cdots,5$.  I do not see any relationship between the orders of the elements and the order of their products in $C_6$.  I stared at a list of the elements (and their orders) of the modulo $31$ multiplicative group.  I don't see anything that helps me answer this question.  Also, I should mention this exercise is in chapter $4$, Cyclic Groups, of the text  and nothing very "deep" has been discussed in the previous chapters.

Comment: 31 is a prime number, so all nontrivial elements are of order 31

Comment: @ janmarqz  No,  I mean modulo 30 MULTIPLICATION.  I picked 31 so the 30 elements would have "lots" of different orders as 30 has "lots" (8) of divisors.

Comment: Sorry but you accepted the answer below much too quickly since one can be more precise than $|ab|$ divides $|a|\cdot|b|$.

Comment: Even though I already accepted the answer below could you plese give a more precise answer.

Comment: @Did, Can you please explain why |ab| can't be multiple of lcm (m, n)? Why is it a divisor of lcm (m, n)? How do I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  As you say $(ab)^n=a^nb^n=????$  That restricts the possibilities for $|ab|$ quite a bit.  Can you show that all of them can be attained?  In addition modulo $n$ all elements commute, which is handy.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by (a*b)^n = a^n*b^n = ????.    The only thing I can think of is this: Since a^|a|=e and b^|b| = e, we could say that (a*b)^n = a^(n - |a|)*b^(n - |b|).  But so what?

Comment: You have $a^n=e=b^n$, so $(ab)^n=a^nb^n=ee=e$

Comment: Now I am really confused.  Are you assuming that |a| = |b| = n ?

Comment: Yes, I was.  If they have different orders, let $a^n=e=b^m$.  Then $(ab)^{\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)}=e$, so the order of $ab$ must be some factor of $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$

Comment: OK thanks.  So the answer by avid19 is not quite correct.  We can say |ab| divides the lcm(|a|,|b|). Right?

Comment: That is right.  Not all factors of $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$ are achievable.  For example, if $n \neq m$ you can't get $1$ because that would require that $a=b^{-1}$ and they would have to have the same order.  As I play with it, I am having trouble getting anything but $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$

Comment: Are you looking for an example of |ab| < lcm(|a|,|b|) ?  In {1,2,...,30} under Mod 31 multiplication on   |2| = 5,  |3| = 30, |6| = 6.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer:  Thanks. I was working with $|a|, |b|$ coprime, which they don't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|ab|=r$
Suppose $t=\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$.
Then $m$ divides $t$ and $n$ divides $t$.
Therefore we have, $t=mk$ and $t=nl$ for some integers $k$ and $l$.
Now $$(ab) ^ t= (a^t)(b^t) =(a^mk) (a^nl) =(e^k) (e^l) =e$$
So we have $(ab) ^t= e$ and $|ab|=r$
This implies $r$ divides $t$.
Therefore the possibilities for $|ab|$ are divisors of $\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$.